# how to load a list of images from assets in Android?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, android-drawable, android-assets

```
private void changePicture(int stageIndex){

    try{

        iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        Picture picture=new Picture();
        String v =picture.getPicFileName();
        InputStream ims = getAssets().open(v);
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
        iv.setImageDrawable(d);
        }catch(IOException ex){
           return;
        }       
}
```

I want to load a list of images from `/asset` folder, so I wrote this function, but it doesn't work. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if your images are stored in `image` folder in assets directory then, the list can be displayed as follows

```
private List<String> getImage(Context context) throws IOException
{
  AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
  String[] files = assetManager.list("image");  
  List<String> it=Arrays.asList(files);
  return it;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap bm;
bm = getBitmapFromAsset("images" + File.separator + image.trim());
System.out.println("bmh==>"+bm.getHeight()+" "+"bmw==>"+bm.getWidth());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);


 /**
 * Retrieves Bitmap from Asset
 * @param strName
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 */
    private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName) throws IOException {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream istr = assetManager.open(strName);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
        istr.close();
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Try the above code within a loop and save all the bitmaps within an array of bitmaps or an arraylist.

Note:Create a folder **images** within the asset folder and store all images within that folder.

**image:** It is the name of the image.

Comment: If `getBitmapFromAsset` is your method then post it too so it will be helpful to OP.

Comment: Its okay. No problem at all. Cheer !!